# Bootstrap column to be slide-in on mobiles

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a col-lg-3 col-lg-9 layout and i want the col-lg-3 to be slide-in menu when i visit on mobile (meaning col-sm-3 and col-xs-3).

I want to have a button floated on the left of the page saying "Menu" and when i click on it the menu to slide in

This is only for the col-sm-3 and col-xs-3 layout.

Any suggestions on that?

This is my code

```
<div class="container">
    <aside class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <div id="filters">
            this should be slide in when on mobile
        </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
        body
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this might give you an insight how this can be done https://jsfiddle.net/yuyokk/sad7yv2p/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I forgot about the sliding thing, now its done:
[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e9trje93/)

The code:

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slide').hide();
});

$('#slide_button').click(function () {
    $('#slide').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <aside class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <div id="filters" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <!-- Other content -->
        </div
        <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
            <button id="slide_button">Slide it</button>
            <div id="slide">I'm some sliding content</div>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) The problem with your solution is that the #filters div is not being displayed on the bigger screens. I want the filters to be visible on lg and md and when i change to sm or xs to be transformed as a slide in column